# Возможноли вызвать консоль linux из php?

Tags: php, linux

Возможно ли вызвать linux консоль из php, и отослать в нее комманды.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно выполнить команды используя функцию [exec();](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php)

При условии что данная функция не заблокирована в php.ini

Comment: Спасибо огромное робит:)